# Misbehaving Case Statement

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm messing around in Ruby some more. I have a file containing a class with two methods and the following code:

```
if __FILE__ == $0

  seq = NumericSequence.new

  puts "\n1. Fibonacci Sequence"
  puts "\n2. Pascal\'s Triangle"
  puts "\nEnter your selection: "
  choice = gets
  puts "\nExcellent choice."

  choice = case
  when 1
    puts "\n\nHow many fibonacci numbers would you like? "
    limit = gets.to_i
    seq.fibo(limit) { |x| puts "Fibonacci number: #{x}\n" }
  when 2
    puts "\n\nHow many rows of Pascal's Triangle would you like?"
    n = gets.to_i
    (0..n).each {|num| seq.pascal_triangle_row(num) \
       {|row| puts "#{row} "}; puts "\n"}
  end

end
```

How come if I run the code and supply option 2, it still runs the first case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `case` syntax is wrong. Should be like this:

```
case choice
  when '1'
    some code
  when '2'
    some other code
end
```

Take a look [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#case).

You also need to compare your variable against strings, as `gets` reads and returns user input as a string.

Comment: Don't forget to chomp: `case choice.chomp`

Comment: Another good example for Ruby case statements: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#S5

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is this:  `choice = case` should be `case choice`.

You're providing a case statement with no "default" object, so the first clause, `when 1`, always returns true.

Effectively, you've written:  `choice = if 1 then ... elsif 2 then ... end`

And, as Mladen mentioned, compare strings to strings or convert to int: `choice = gets.to_i`